# why does my router route me through Michigan when I live in Maryland?

Tags: networking

I used to live in Michigan, I now live in Maryland and now have a local web service provider. I have discovered that my computer for some reason still thinks I am in Michigan (web map services and google analytics). I noticed that this shows up whenever I am running a program that is supposed to hide your IP address.

Comment: Well, isn't it a good thing that the IP-hiding program does not show your real location? I mean, you get two birds with one stone!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not that you are being routed through Michigan, but that programs still remember that you are from Michigan, and have not checked since then.  Clearing your cookies should fix most of them.

Answer (score 0):

"Hiding" your IP address works by sending all your traffic through another computer (called a proxy), so that websites see connections coming from the proxy computer, not your real one.  It's likely that the proxy you're using is located in Michigan.